# Programmatically sort product Collection

Tags: collection, product-collection, sorting

I have a product collection.  How does one go about sorting this collection the Magento Way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easymoden00b,Magento  have a magic function `addAttributeToSort()` which is sort your product Collection on `basic of product attribute`

**Format:**

```
$ProductCollectionObject->addAttributeToSort('attribute_code', 'sort_order')
```

**Example:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Here i have filter the product collection  by `created_at` attribute

Comment: this works -- although curiously it is only sorting the first 20 products of my catalog when I increase the amount displayed on the page (40, 60, etc).

Comment: it also work for all limit of products .it may be cache issue

Comment: Why could be the reason that is not woking for me?...once I run the foreach, the loop starts since the first entity_id :/